# Hadoop 2.9.0 - hadoop namenode -format and hdfs-site.xml dfs.namenode.name.dir

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My 1st question, I'll try not to screw up too bad :)

I am installing Hadoop 2.9.0 on a 4 nodes cluster, for learning purpose.
I have started with namenode installation/configuration following the official Apache Hadoop 2.9.0 documentation and some google pages.

I edited my hdfs-site.xml located under $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop directory like so :

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///apps/hdfs/namenode/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///apps/hdfs/datanode/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>file:///apps/hdfs/namesecondary/data</value>
  </property>
```

When I run the "hadoop namenode -format" it format the default $hadoop.tmp.dir under /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/...

Found some pages that said to set the HADOOP_CONF_DIR to where the XML configurations files are (ie : $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop) but also some that said the opposite, to not set it.

In my case, it did fix my problem but not sure if it's the right modification?

If anyone could help me out to understand this, it would be great :)

Thank alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what problem you were having, but there's a default setting for `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` which is set in a `hadoop-env.sh` file that's loaded prior to all hadoop commands.

I believe this might be simply `/etc/hadoop`. At least, that's where most clusters store the configs

Since your files are elsewhere, you needed to export that value to something else, which is fine.

Personally, I suggest use Apache Ambari instead of manual managing and installing more than 2 nodes. It'll ensure your configs are matching and additionally monitor the services

Comment: Hi,

I will take a look at that hadoop-env.sh file. Most probably I missed that HADOOO_CONF_DIR setting in it.

And for Ambari, I will install it, just want to install hdfs first to learn 

Thanks alot!

Comment: In my $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh, the parameter seems to be set correctly :

`code`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}`code`
which resolve to /etc/hadoop

Comment: ** Ignore above comment ... **
In my $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh, the parameter seems to be set correctly :

`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}`

which resolve to /etc/hadoop
I have defined my HADOOP_HOME in my .bash_profile and it works fine.

My configuration files are under $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop which is the default location, isn't it ?

Anyway, as you suggested, I will redo with Ambari :)
Learning something new is great!

Comment: No, as pointed out, the default location is in the root folder, `/etc/hadoop`, which has no record of the `HADOOP_HOME` variable. You've exported the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` so that it's within `HADOOP_HOME`

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood!
You literally meant /etc/hadoop and not $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop, my bad.

Yes, then, I have no hadoop binaires under /etc/hadoop. It is under /apps/hdfs. So that mean, I should export that HADOOP_CONF_DIR so it does not use the default location, as defined in hadoop-env.sh file.

Ok, I think I got it this time :)

Thanks alot!